# Change Navigation Hover color

Tags: css

URL: http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/

How can I change the hover color of the second level navigation categories "Outdoor" "living" .... ect?

I have looked through the CSS and cant find the appropriate .hover class.. Also looked through the files for a possible JPG that I could just photoshop, no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome I right-clicked the link and selected "Inspect Element". From there I can see all the CSS applied to the element. By unticking this one, the hover effect changed back to the default pink, so this is the line:

```
.s_secondary_color, a:hover, #categories > ul > li > a, #footer_categories h2, .pagination a, #view_mode .s_selected a {
color: #666;
}
```

Lines 43-51 of the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

They are links, it's probably not a .hover class but an a:hover.  Look for that.